# Hibernate search storing byte[] in index

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, arrays, hibernate-search

I have following config in my POJO:

```
@Field(index = Index.NO, store = Store.YES)
private byte[] file;
```

When I start my Apps container I get following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to guess FieldBridge for file
>       at org.hibernate.search.bridge.BridgeFactory.guessType(BridgeFactory.java:249)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.AbstractDocumentBuilder.bindFieldAnnotation(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:707)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.AbstractDocumentBuilder.checkForField(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:568)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeMemberLevelAnnotations(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:436)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeClass(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:383)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.AbstractDocumentBuilder.checkForIndexedEmbedded(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:631)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeMemberLevelAnnotations(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:440)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeClass(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:383)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.AbstractDocumentBuilder.(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:134)
>       at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:178)
>       at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:375)
>       at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:262)
>       at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:144)
>       at org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:151)
>       at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$1.processListener(EventListeners.java:198)
>       at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.processListeners(EventListeners.java:181)
>       at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:194)
>       ... 41 more

## How do I store byte array in Hibernate Search (Lucene) index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a [field bridge](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e3589).

For example:

```
@Field(index = Index.NO, store = Store.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl = MyFieldBridge.class)
private byte[] file;


//The file bridge
public class MyFieldBridge implements StringBridge {

    @Override
    public String objectToString(final Object object) {

        byte[] file = (byte[]) object;

        return MagicFileUtil.getTextContent(file)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mat Banik: no the MagicFileUtil  is something that you have to write by your own.